# Not able to load external content on cordova and windows phone

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, reactjs, windows-phone, phonegap-build

I have an app for Windows Phone built with Cordova + React + Parse.

The app works fine during development and debug, but the calls made via Parse on the published app aren't working.

Also, the app is built using Phonegap Build.

Comment: Please post your `config.xml`.  Did you apply the `whitelist` system?

Comment: I'm moving from my location. I'll be offline for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this line to the `config.xml` to fix it.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/ >
```